# How to reattach multiselect in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, multi-select

I have mulutiselect option enabled in select html code, my frontend look like this: [image]

For example if user unselect some option and select other how can I update it in database, any idea?

Comment: I believe this question is not specifically related to Laravel. Could you at least show your table's schema so we could help you on the way you should link your queries/tables?

Comment: `sync()` method is what you are after. search for `sync` here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Comment: Aha but how deattach option with `sync()` if option is unselected?

Comment: For example admin decide to change client from `Zamora` to `Real` and he unselect `Zamora` and select `Real` and click edit.. How to make in database to deattach Zamora and attach Real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `ManyToMany` relationships between say `Group` and `Project` you can use `sync()` method to maintain association as below,

```
$group->projects()->sync([$projId1, $projId2]);
```

Above will remove all previous association between current group(`$group`) and projects and associates newly supplied projects i.e. `$projId1, $projId2`.

If you want to maintain previous associations pass `false` as a second argument in `sync()` as below,

```
$group->projects()->sync([$projId1, $projId2], false);
```

Above code will maintain previous `Group` and `Project` association and will also associate passed projects.

Comment: Thanks, I have now new problem please chack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292695/how-to-use-sync-with-pivot-laravel-5